# How can i add page indicator among three different activity in android?

Tags: android

I want to add page indicator at the bottom of next button in android.

I have three Activity

1) MainActivity 
2) FirstActivity 
3) SecondActivity

I want to add page indicator. Refer Image.

[image]

I want to add page indicator at the bottom of these activity how can i do this ?

1) MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn_main_next;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn_main_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_main_next);
        btn_main_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        });
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class));
    }
}
```

activity_main-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="neeraj.com.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Main Activity"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />



    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:backgroundTint="#00b200"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="125dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_main_next" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

2) FirstActivity:-

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn_first_next;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);


        btn_first_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_first_next);
        btn_first_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        });
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
    }

    }
```

activity_first:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="FirstActity"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />


    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:backgroundTint="#00b200"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="125dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_first_next" />
</LinearLayout>
```

3) SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn_second_next;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        btn_second_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_second_next);
        btn_second_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        });
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    }

}
```

activity_second:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="SecondActivity"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"


        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />


    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:backgroundTint="#00b200"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="125dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_second_next" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @AlvinVarghese If I use fragment then how can i do same?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a **Slider** with page indicator by using `ViewPager` and `Fragment`.

Here is an good tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

Hope this will help! Thank you~

Comment: If i don't want to use ViewPager and Fragment then what i can do ?

Comment: To achieve this you must use Fragment. An activity can contain multiple fragments. Fragments are mostly a sub part of an activity.